# CSS Style in JSP

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I have a JAVA EE app. deployed in a Tomcat 7 where I have this JSP and I want to apply a style to the footer to center the text, so I define the style in the JSP to be applied in the footer DIV

```
<%@ page import="com.telefonica.movistar.vo.UserVO" %>
<%@ page import="com.telefonica.movistar.dao.MonitorProcessDAO" %>
<%@ page import="com.telefonica.movistar.vo.MonitorProcessVO" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>

<style>
.layout-footer {
    border-width: 1px 0;
    justify-content: center
}
</style>

<%
  MonitorProcessDAO dao = new MonitorProcessDAO();

  String action = request.getParameter("action");
  String reference = request.getParameter("reference");

  if ("keepalive".equals(action)) {
    dao.keepAlive(reference);
  } else
  if ("setmetrics".equals(action)) {
    String metric1 = request.getParameter("metric1");
    String metric2 = request.getParameter("metric2");
    String metric3 = request.getParameter("metric3");
    dao.setMetrics(reference, metric1, metric2, metric3);
  } else
  if ("reporterror".equals(action)) {
      String message = request.getParameter("message");
    dao.reportError(reference, message);
  } else {
%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="windows-1252"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mobile/mobileWS.css" media="screen" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" name="MobileOptimized">
    <title>Process Monitoring</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><b>Now:</b> <%=(new java.util.Date())%></p>
    <table>
    <tr bgcolor="#E0E0E0">
      <td><b>Reference</b></td>
      <td><b>KeepaliveDate</b></td>
      <td><b>Metric1</b></td>
      <td><b>Metric2</b></td>
      <td><b>Metric3</b></td>
      <td width="100%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

<%
  ArrayList list = dao.list(null);
  for (int i=0;(list!=null)&&(i<list.size());i++) {
    MonitorProcessVO vo = (MonitorProcessVO)list.get(i);

    String bgcolor= ((i%2)!=0) ? "#F0F0F0" : "#FFFFFF";
%>
    <tr bgcolor="<%=bgcolor%>">
      <td nowrap><%=vo.getReference()%></td>
      <td nowrap><%=vo.getKeepaliveDate()%></td>
      <td nowrap><%=vo.getMetric1Value()%></td>
      <td nowrap><%=vo.getMetric2Value()%></td>
      <td nowrap><%=vo.getMetric3Value()%></td>
    </tr>
<%
  }
%>    
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table>
    <tr bgcolor="#E0E0E0">
      <td><b>Reference</b></td>
      <td><b>ErrorDate</b></td>
      <td width="100%"><b>Message</b></td>
    </tr>

<%
  list = dao.listError(null);
  for (int i=0;(list!=null)&&(i<list.size());i++) {
    MonitorProcessVO vo = (MonitorProcessVO)list.get(i);

    String bgcolor= ((i%2)!=0) ? "#F0F0F0" : "#FFFFFF";
%>
    <tr bgcolor="<%=bgcolor%>">
      <td nowrap><%=vo.getReference()%></td>
      <td nowrap><%=vo.getErrorDate()%></td>
      <td nowrap><%=vo.getErrorMessage()%></td>
    </tr>
<%
  }
%>    
    </table>
    <br/>
    <table>
    <tr bgcolor="#E0E0E0">
      <td width="100%"><b>Daily Reports</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td nowrap><a href="../reports/generic_html.jsp?guiUserId=10191&reportId=973&view=V_RPT_SAV_TELEFONO_STATUS">Aggregation Logs</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <td nowrap><a href="../reports/generic_html.jsp?guiUserId=191001&reportId=83&view=V_ABONADOS_MONITORING_DAY">Aggregation Monitoring</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="layout-footer" style="align">
        <br/><br/>
        Build 1.0.0  -  (07/11/2017)  &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; &copy; Telefonica 2017
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
<% 
  } 
%>
```

but the footer does not apply the style and I see the text align to the left for all the browsersL IE, chrome and Firefox

Comment: You should not be putting scriptlet code in JSPs.  Learn JSTL if you must continue with JSPs.  You should not be embedding CSS in the page this way, either.  Externalize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing the display: flex part. Otherwise the justify-content won't work.

```
.layout-footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
}
```